# Github branch protection bypass status checks

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a push action, that runs an automated tag update, This works when i used a `bypass user token` like below:

```
name: Push

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v2'
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
          fetch-depth: 50

      - name: Automated Version Bump
        id: version-bump
        uses: 'phips28/gh-action-bump-version@master'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.BYPASS }}
        with:
          skip-tag: 'false'
```

We want to add status checks on pull requests to show tests pass etc. But when adding them a repo that has automated tag updates (ie has the above action on pull) the above action fails, because its trying to run the PR

I was expecting the `bypass` user to bypass the status checks but it clearly doesnt.

error is:

```
✖  fatal     remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.        
remote: error: Required status check "pre-commit" is expected.        
To https://github.comrepository.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/repository.git'
```

Any ideas how to work around this? running the status checks again seems a time waste, setting the status checks to NOT be needed, side steps the point of them.

Thanks

Comment: What does `phips28/gh-action-bump-version@master` do?

Comment: It does an automated tag update of the repo based on semver commits and a package.json file, so it does commit to master to update the package.json after every push to master, u though running the push command as a bypass PR user would skip the checks but seems not